# Convert transitive closure table into adjacency list

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchical-data

I have materialized transitive closures table I called GRAPH_TBL. Code below

I am running Oracle 11gR2.

I want to apologize for providing incomplete data to my question. Please see correct and more complete data below:

My table

```
CREATE TABLE "GRAPH_TBL"
("PARENT_NAME" VARCHAR2(80 CHAR), 
"CHILD_NAME" VARCHAR2(80 CHAR), 
"PARENT_ID" VARCHAR2(18 CHAR), 
"CHILD_ID" VARCHAR2(18 CHAR), 
"RELATIVE_LEVEL" NUMBER(18,0)
);
```

Data:

```
Insert into GRAPH_TBL PARENT_NAME,CHILD_NAME,PARENT_ID,CHILD_ID,RELATIVE_LEVEL) values ('Components','Components','a044100000171bXAAQ','a044100000171bXAAQ',0);
Insert into GRAPH_TBL (PARENT_NAME,CHILD_NAME,PARENT_ID,CHILD_ID,RELATIVE_LEVEL) values ('Processors','Processors','a044100000171bYAAQ','a044100000171bYAAQ',0);
Insert into GRAPH_TBL (PARENT_NAME,CHILD_NAME,PARENT_ID,CHILD_ID,RELATIVE_LEVEL) values ('Intel','Intel','a044100000171bZAAQ','a044100000171bZAAQ',0);
Insert into GRAPH_TBL (PARENT_NAME,CHILD_NAME,PARENT_ID,CHILD_ID,RELATIVE_LEVEL) values ('Xeon 5600','Xeon 5600','a044100000171bdAAA','a044100000171bdAAA',0);
Insert into GPMETLSTAGE.GRAPH_TBL (PARENT_NAME,CHILD_NAME,PARENT_ID,CHILD_ID,RELATIVE_LEVEL) values ('Intel','Xeon 5600','a044100000171bZAAQ','a044100000171bdAAA',1);
Insert into GRAPH_TBL (PARENT_NAME,CHILD_NAME,PARENT_ID,CHILD_ID,RELATIVE_LEVEL) values ('Processors','Intel','a044100000171bYAAQ','a044100000171bZAAQ',1);
Insert into GRAPH_TBL (PARENT_NAME,CHILD_NAME,PARENT_ID,CHILD_ID,RELATIVE_LEVEL) values ('Processors','Xeon 5600','a044100000171bYAAQ','a044100000171bdAAA',2);
Insert into GRAPH_TBL (PARENT_NAME,CHILD_NAME,PARENT_ID,CHILD_ID,RELATIVE_LEVEL) values ('Xeon 5600','Intel Xeon E5645 2.4Ghz, 12M Cache,Turbo, HT, 1333MHz Max Mem','a044100000171bdAAA','a044100000171grAAA',1);
Insert into GRAPH_TBL (PARENT_NAME,CHILD_NAME,PARENT_ID,CHILD_ID,RELATIVE_LEVEL) values ('Components','Processors','a044100000171bXAAQ','a044100000171bYAAQ',1);
Insert into GRAPH_TBL (PARENT_NAME,CHILD_NAME,PARENT_ID,CHILD_ID,RELATIVE_LEVEL) values ('Eclipse Products and Services','Eclipse Products and Services','a044100000171aQAAQ','a044100000171aQAAQ',0);
Insert into GRAPH_TBL (PARENT_NAME,CHILD_NAME,PARENT_ID,CHILD_ID,RELATIVE_LEVEL) values ('Components','Intel','a044100000171bXAAQ','a044100000171bZAAQ',2);
Insert into GRAPH_TBL (PARENT_NAME,CHILD_NAME,PARENT_ID,CHILD_ID,RELATIVE_LEVEL) values ('Components','Xeon 5600','a044100000171bXAAQ','a044100000171bdAAA',3);
Insert into GRAPH_TBL (PARENT_NAME,CHILD_NAME,PARENT_ID,CHILD_ID,RELATIVE_LEVEL) values ('Eclipse Products and Services','Processors','a044100000171aQAAQ','a044100000171bYAAQ',2);
Insert into GRAPH_TBL (PARENT_NAME,CHILD_NAME,PARENT_ID,CHILD_ID,RELATIVE_LEVEL) values ('Eclipse Products and Services','Intel','a044100000171aQAAQ','a044100000171bZAAQ',3);
Insert into GRAPH_TBL (PARENT_NAME,CHILD_NAME,PARENT_ID,CHILD_ID,RELATIVE_LEVEL) values ('Eclipse Products and Services','Xeon 5600','a044100000171aQAAQ','a044100000171bdAAA',4);
Insert into GRAPH_TBL (PARENT_NAME,CHILD_NAME,PARENT_ID,CHILD_ID,RELATIVE_LEVEL) values ('Eclipse Products and Services','Components','a044100000171aQAAQ','a044100000171bXAAQ',1);
Insert into GRAPH_TBL (PARENT_NAME,CHILD_NAME,PARENT_ID,CHILD_ID,RELATIVE_LEVEL) values ('Intel Xeon E5645 2.4Ghz, 12M Cache,Turbo, HT, 1333MHz Max Mem','Intel Xeon E5645 2.4Ghz, 12M Cache,Turbo, HT, 1333MHz Max Mem','a044100000171grAAA','a044100000171grAAA',0);
commit;
```

This is just a sample of one path from leaf level up to the root of the tree.
So this particular tree looks like this from top to leaf node:

```
Eclipse Products and Services (this is my root, also some category)
 Components (some category)
  Processors (some category)
   Intel (some category)
    Xeon 5600 (some category)
     Intel Xeon E5645 2.4Ghz, 12M Cache,Turbo, HT, 1333MHz Max Mem (this is my leaf node, product)
```

relative level indicates edges of the graph for categories:
0 - node itself
1 - next direct immediate node (direct parent - child relationship)
2 - one hop over
3 - two hops over
4 - three hops over

relative levels >=2 are defined only for categories but not for leaf (actual product)

Please help me to convert it into Adjacency List using SQL.
My expected output should look like this:

```
NAME                                                            ID  PARENT_ID
Eclipse Products and Services                                   a044100000171aQAAQ  null
Components                                                      a044100000171bXAAQ  a044100000171aQAAQ
Processors                                                      a044100000171bYAAQ  a044100000171bXAAQ
Intel                                                           a044100000171bZAAQ  a044100000171bYAAQ
Xeon 5600                                                       a044100000171bdAAA  a044100000171bZAAQ
Intel Xeon E5645 2.4Ghz, 12M Cache,Turbo, HT, 1333MHz Max Mem   a044100000171grAAA  a044100000171bdAAA
```

Thank you for your time and help!

Comment: Why does `5` have only `4` as its parent?  What is the logic behind not showing `1` and `2`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
with tbl(PARENT_ID,CHILD_ID) as
(select 1,2 from dual union all
select 1,3 from dual union all
select 1,4 from dual union all
select 1,5 from dual union all
select 2,3 from dual union all
select 2,4 from dual union all
select 2,5 from dual union all
select 4,5 from dual
)
select 
    nvl(c.child_id,p.parent_id) as id
    ,c.parent_id
from 
    (select child_id,
    max(parent_id) as parent_id from tbl 
    group by child_id
    ) c
full join
    (select distinct parent_id as parent_id from tbl) p
on c.child_id=p.parent_id
order by id
```

Output

```
+----+-----------+
| id | PARENT_ID |
+----+-----------+
|  1 |           |
|  2 |         1 |
|  3 |         2 |
|  4 |         2 |
|  5 |         4 |
+----+-----------+
```

Explanation:

The first derived table `c` which get `max(parent)` group by `child`. In this case, you will get child `2,3,4,5`. But as `1` has no child, it will not be given in output. To do it, you need `full join` on `distinct` `parent_id` so you will also get the `parent` where there is no `child`.

We need `nvl` or `coalesce` or `case` in select clause to take `parent_id` from derived table `p` when `child_id` `is null`.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion! I apologize, but I corrected my question by providing correct actual and more complete data I have.